# File name starting with *\*

Tags: shell, unix

I have some weird file in my home directory which name is `\e[m`.
I am using Linux. How can I delete it because I tried `rm` but it says `no such file or directory found`?

Answer (score 13):

If none of the other answers posted here are working, you can always try removing a file based on its inode.

To do that:

1. Find the file's inode by doing `ls -i`. Let's suppose the inode number is `123456` for `\e[m`.
2. Delete the file based on its inode number: run either `find -inum 123456 -delete` or `find -inum 123456 -exec rm {} \;`.

Comment: Upvoted, but note `-delete` is probably better than `-exec rm {} \;`.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I've updated the post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: @kampu: `-delete` is not required by the POSIX standard for `find`, so it may not be available in all implementations of `find`.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, the easiest thing would be to use a file manager that by passes any shell-globing.

Using a shell, I'd try using the shell completion system (assuming you are using a shell with such). Like `rm [TAB]`, if your shell gives you a menu and allows you to pick from the menu or cycle through it, you should be able to get completion that is text representation that your shell will recognize.

Answer (score 1):

Possible ways:

```
rm \\e\[m
```

or

```
rm '\e[m'
```

or

```
rm "\\e[m"
```

Comment: doesn't work... still says no such file or directory

Comment: You may have an unprintable character in the file name then. You could try using wild cards such as `rm '\e'*`

Comment: `rm "$HOME"'/\e[m'`?

Comment: Maybe the actual name of the file is not `\e[m`?

Answer (score 1):

If `\e` is an escape character (ASCII code 27), and you are using the Bash shell, you could try:

```
rm $'\e[m'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob expansion. try `ls *[[]m`, and if that only returns this file, then you can safely do `rm *[[]m`.

If the offending file is not listed with the above `ls` command, it certainly contains an escape and the 'm' is not actually a literal m (and/or the `[` is not a literal `[`)